# InfoPath - This form cannot be filled out .... read-only version of this form?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, readonly

In my project I am using InfoPath and I store the xml it produces in database (through a WS) - so there is no SharePoint along the way.

When I open the InfoPath form the server it always shows this weird message:

This form cannot be filled out, either because you do not have adequate permissions, another user has the form open, or the form is opened in another program.
Do you want to open a read-only version of this form?

After clicking Yes - InfoPath will open the form, let you do all your changes, basically working as expected. It is the message that confuses the users I need to get rid of...

Please note that I don't have any FrontPage extensions installed (and I am not likely getting those installed).

Thank you for any help!
Jarda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google book preview with your answer](http://books.google.com/books?id=XKKWuSHExC8C&pg=PA435&lpg=PA435&dq=infopath+%22This+form+cannot+be+filled+out%22+message&source=bl&ots=jiu7INquz2&sig=vR8WioQet9hOMtQDr58KJQNz8LM&hl=en&ei=QmXQSYzWDJLstQPskLigAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=5&ct=result)

I am unable to select the text since this is a scanned book, but essentially it says that this may be addressed by a later version of Infopath. For now users will need to ignore this message, or you need to expose write-access on your server to filled out forms even if you intend for users to submit rather than save completed forms.

Comment: Might have just been luck.

Google query was:
infopath "This form cannot be filled out, either because you do not have adequate permissions"

Result was near the bottom of the first page.